# Can I stop GCC including standard library names into the global namespace?

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces

When I use Standard C headers in C++, I generally prefer the forms which place identifiers into the `std` namespace, such as `<cstdlib>`.  However, when I use these, GCC also places the names into the global namespace, which means that it will accept programs such as this:

```
#include <cstddef>

std::size_t x;
size_t y;

int main() {}
```

Here, the declaration of `x` is correct, but the declaration of `y` should be rejected if I want my code to be portable.  (Note that if I included `<stddef.h>` instead of `<cstddef>`, GCC *will* correctly reject the declaration of `x`).

Can I get GCC to reject the declaration `y` above?

I compiled with all the pedantry and warnings I could think of:

```
-std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Weffc++
```

None of those seem to prevent GCC from accepting the non-portable form.

---

I'm now unsure whether I understand the rules correctly; my knowledge comes from this section in CPP Reference:

> ### C compatibility headers
>
> For some of the C standard library headers of the form `xxx.h`, the C++ standard library both includes an
>   identically-named header and another header of the form `cxxx`.
>
> With the exception of `complex.h`, each `xxx.h` header included in the C++
>   standard library places in the global namespace each name that the
>   corresponding `cxxx` header would have placed in the `std` namespace.
>
> These headers are allowed to also declare the same names in the `std`
>   namespace, and the corresponding `cxxx` headers are allowed to also
>   declare the same names in the global namespace: including `<cstdlib>`
>   definitely provides `std::malloc` and may also provide `::malloc`.
>   Including `<stdlib.h>` definitely provides `::malloc` and may also provide
>   `std::malloc`. This applies even to functions and function overloads
>   that are not part of C standard library.

To me, that last paragraph indicates that GCC's behaviour is permitted but not required, and therefore it's wrong to depend on it.

Comment: You could write an `#include` inside a namespace. Not sure if it's a good idea

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 sounds like a really bad idea :(

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I think this would be a horrible idea since the same hader can be included by other headers and you just end up with even more duplicated types in different namespaces.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: that would be a truck load of UB.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0, I don't think that's something I'd want to expose in my production code, even if it were safe!

Comment: The closest you will get is using Oracle's Studio compiler on Solaris. As far as I know, they are the only ones who bothered trying to keep the global namespace clean. There are some vestigial __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD etc in glibc but they never worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is that `#include <xxx.h>` (where `xxx.h` is the name of a standard C header) is **required** to define all the names required by the C standard for that header in the global namespace, and is **allowed** to also define those names (with the same meaning) in namespace `std`. Similarly, `#include <cxxx>` (where `cxxx` is the name of one of the standard C++ headers for the standard C library) is **required** to define all the names from the corresponding C header (with the same meaning) in the namespace `std`, and is **allowed** to also define those names in the global namespace.

Back in C++ 98 those headers were not allowed to add names to the other namespace. Some compiler couldn't do that. For example, if the C++ library writers don't control the C headers, the usual implementation technique is for the C++ header to `#include` the C header and hoist the C names into `std` with using declarations. So the rule was changed to reflect reality.

The language definition does **not** require those headers to put the names in both places; if it did, then the `cxxx` headers wouldn't be needed.

In short, you can't count on `#include <cxxx>` putting C names into the global namespace, but you also can't count on it not putting them there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately these headers must also define all the types from corresponding c header.

> **18.4.1 Header  synopsis** [cstdint.syn]
>
> 2 The header defines all types and macros the same as the C standard library header `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Your answer is misleading. It's simply saying that the type provided by `std::size_t` shouldn't vary from the type provided by `size_t` from the C library. The actual language about putting `std::size_t` into the global namespace is in a different section.

Comment: @user141770 Hum. I've always thought that <cstddef> brings in the C types, and punted an answer based on that. Are you saying we're wrong?

Comment: @Bathsheba Where did I say that? I'm saying they're quoting the wrong section. headers#4 says "Except as noted in Clauses [library] through [thread] and Annex [depr], the contents of each header cname is the same as that of the corresponding header name.h as specified in the C standard library." A typical implementation will do `namespace std { using ::size_t }`. If accessing `size_t` was a compiler error, this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @user141770 You are correct that `std::size_t` is described in other parts, but the quoted parts states rather explicitly that these headers also define types from corresponding C library header while listing all the in-namespace declarations in section 1. It actually makes sense to require declarations of all these types in global namespace.

Comment: @VTT Synopses sections are not normative. Otherwise, GCC would be non-conforming as it does `using ::size_t` instead of `using size_t = ...`. It's "clear" to me that the paragraph 2 is suggesting that the implementation should use the same type as defined in the C header.

Comment: `cstdint` is the wrong header anyway. It's `cstddef`.

Answer (score -1):

> but the declaration of y should be rejected if I want my code to be
>   portable

Be reassured that your code will be portable: but sadly there is no way of getting `std::size_t` without `size_t`. That's because `#include <cstddef>` is required to bring in the C types defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Since you can't "undefine" a type in C++, your only recourse is the use of static analysis tools: then you can enforce any style rule that tickles your fancy.

Comment: Are you saying that this behaviour is actually *required*?  I guess that's good (because my code is then portable) even though it's bad (I would like a "clean" global namespace).

Comment: Yes, it is required by standard C++.

Comment: I've edited my question to include an extract from CPP Reference - can you show how the statement there is wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong per se, but other parts of the standard remove that optionality.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- I don't know what other parts you're referring to, but the intention is that `#include <xxx.h>` puts the C names in the global namespace and is **allowed to** put the names in `std` as well, and that `#include <cxxx.h>` puts the C names in `std` and is **allowed to** put the names in the global namespace as well. The history here is that originally putting them in the wrong place was prohibited, but in some environments that couldn't be done, so we added language that allowed putting them in the other place as well. If each had to do both there would be no need for the Cxxx ones.